# perform_destroy: change the value before deleting instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

How to change value the save it in db in perform_destroy.

I want to set cancel value to True when user is try to delete the instance

```py
def perform_destroy(self,instance):
      instance.cancel = True
      instance.save()
```

i try this but nothings change in db.

Comment: What is `perform_destroy`? Are you using `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals to call this as a handler?

Comment: in vewset {viewsets.ModelViewSet} there is method perform_destroy